# Adding a new version for .xcdatamodel model with inheritance inside

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have SQLite Database in my app with CoreData models. And there is a big issue while trying to add a new version of .xcdatamodel

Base model:
[image]

The last model, migration from the base one to this one is done:

[image: base core data model]

`Tree` in the Parent entity for `Maple`

[image: Maple's parent entity is Tree]

I would like to add a new entity. It will not be connected to the current entities.

The new model should look like this:

[image: Core Data model showing new entity, Animal]

I tried to use options to migrate database automatically:

```
self.persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true])
```

The problem:

> Property named ‘height’ in entity ‘Maple’ conflicts with property inherited from parent entity ‘Tree’

But there is no such field in the `Maple` entity. Any ideas on how it could be solved? Any guides on how to remove this inheritance are also welcome.

Update: Maybe the issue could be connected with iOS 14.

Comment: Did you have a previous version of your data model where `Maple` had that property? Also what do you mean by "how to remove this inheritance"? You don't want your model to use inheritance?

Comment: @shim One version before Maple had that property, and Tree wasn't a parent. For me will be also ok, if in the next .xcmodel version Tree will not be the parent of Maple if it will avoid such issues in the future.

Comment: If you want to move a property to this new parent entity you'll have to handle that in your migration, as the lightweight migration can't figure that out for you automatically. If you don't want to use inheritance, you don't have to.

Comment: I update the question. Property migration to the parent was done before. I don't want to touch it if it will not affect the new entity creation. There are no expected changes in Tree or Maple in the New model.

Comment: "Property migration to the parent was done before" — you have to make sure to handle the migration from any older version of the model to the current one. Might be why you're seeing that error.